# Replace a paintable with another in vala Gtk4

Tags: vala, gtk4

I want to make my app change image for another when a button is clicked vala with `Gtk4`.

```
 public class Main : Object
{
    public static int main()
    {
        var app = new Gtk.Application ("example.com.Demo", ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE);

        app.activate.connect
        (() => {
            var window = new Gtk.ApplicationWindow(app);

            var image = new Gtk.Picture.for_filename("img1.jpg");
            var button = new Gtk.Button.with_label("Change Image");
            button.clicked.connect(
                // how to change the image
            );

            var box = new Gtk.Box(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, 10);
            box.append(image);
            box.append(button);

            window.set_child(box);
            window.present();
            image.show();
        });
        return app.run();
    }
}
```

I've tried using a `Gtk.Image()` and the method [`image.set_from_paintable`](https://valadoc.org/gtk4/Gtk.Image.set_from_paintable.html#!) which fails with the error:

```
: error: Argument 1: Cannot convert from `Gtk.Picture' to `unowned Gdk.Paintable?'
   29 |                 image.set_paintable(new Gtk.Picture.for_filename("img2.jpg"));
```

I've also tried using a container `var box = new Gtk.Box(...)` removing one `Gtk.Picture` and appending the second one, which I could not make work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked was declaring the two pictures first and using a container to remove the image and append the second:

```
 public class Main : Object
{
    public static int main()
    {
        var app = new Gtk.Application ("example.com.Demo", ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE);

        app.activate.connect
        (() => {
            var window = new Gtk.ApplicationWindow(app);

            var image1 = new Gtk.Picture.for_filename("img1.jpg");
            var image2 = new Gtk.Picture.for_filename("img2.jpg");

            var container = new Gtk.Box(Gtk.Orientation.Vertical, 10);
            container.append(image1);

            var button = new Gtk.Button.with_label("Change Image");
            button.clicked.connect(
                container.remove(image1);
                container.append(image2);
            );

            var box = new Gtk.Box(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, 10);
            box.append(image);
            box.append(button);

            window.set_child(box);
            window.present();
            image.show();
        });
        return app.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: When there are more images, I remove all images (whether they exist or not) and then append the correct one.

This results in this warning:

`Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_box_remove: assertion 'gtk_widget_get_parent (child) == (GtkWidget *)box' failed`

If there's a better way which triggers no warnings I'd be grateful.